# cocos2d errors: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am following the tutorial http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2115. In this tutorial I found a project template and go through it to begin.

I have downloaded cocos2d-iphone-0.99.1 add the subdirectory
cocos2d to project….but when I built I got 9 error and 4 warning

> Scene.h: No such file or directory
>   Director’ undeclared (first use in
>   this function)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:79:24:
>   error: FontManager.h: No such file or
>   directory
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:80:35:
>   error: FontLabelStringDrawing.h: No
>   such file or directory
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:
>   In function ‘-[CCTexture2D(Text)
>   initWithString:fontName:fontSize:]‘:
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:519:
>   error: ‘ZFont’ undeclared (first use
>   in this function)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:519:
>   error: (Each undeclared identifier is
>   reported only once
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:519:
>   error: for each function it appears
>   in.)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:519:
>   error: ‘zFont’ undeclared (first use
>   in this function)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:519:
>   error: ‘FontManager’ undeclared (first
>   use in this function)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:521:
>   warning: ‘NSString’ may not respond to
>   ‘-sizeWithZFont:’
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:521:
>   warning: (Messages without a matching
>   method signature
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:521:
>   warning: will be assumed to return
>   ‘id’ and accept
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:521:
>   warning: ‘…’ as arguments.)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:521:
>   error: incompatible types in
>   assignment
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:
>   In function ‘-[CCTexture2D(Text)
>   initWithString:dimensions:alignment:fontName:fontSize:]‘:
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:567:
>   error: ‘FontManager’ undeclared (first
>   use in this function)
>   /Volumes/Jobed/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:569:
>   warning: ‘NSString’ may not respond to
>   ‘-drawInRect:withZFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:’

etc…. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little while back cocos2d renamed all of their classes.  They now all begin with CC.  In your above example, you should be using CCDirector.h, not Director.h

Have a look at the [cocos2d API](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/annotated.html) for more details.

After looking at the tutorial you posted, it looks like the information contained within it is a little out of date.  I think you'll find the installation instructions especially troublesome.  I'd suggest finding a better tutorial.  There are several posted on the cocos2d site.  [Here's](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test) a more up to date guide on how to install cocos2d.

Edit: I should have posted a link to the [cocos2d programming guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index) directly.  It contains all the information you need to know to get started.

Comment: hi thanks..
but what about 
#import "FontManager.h"
#import "FontLabelStringDrawing.h"

the is no file such as CCFontManager.h...

Comment: Those have all been depreciated. Look at this instead: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:labels

Comment: I actually want to develop an application like funball in app store...
but don't know in which way i should go....the tutorial u give looks good but can u give me link of more tutorial to develop the app??
no matter if the books or tutorials are paid...thanks..

Comment: Honestly your best bet is to just dive in, make mistakes, and Google quite a bit to find answers.  I really don't know of any other good cocos2d tutorials besides the ones I listed, but I know there are quite a bit out there.  Your best bet is to search for them and look at the date they were written to make sure they apply to the more recent versions of cocos2d.